# How to prevent Travis-CI from executing the script if PR and anything else than master

Tags: git, github, travis-ci

Is it possible to make Travis-CI build only once a merge has been done on Master? So not the PR itself, but only after it's merged?

As described in the [documentation](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/customizing-the-build/), I've tried

```
branches:
  only: ["master"]
```

However, once this was filed in as a PR, Travis still built it.

Is there another method possible to prevent all other branches from building?

Comment: I don't know any way other than [testing for PR](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/pull-requests/) when a test is already running: `'if [ "$TRAVIS_PULL_REQUEST" != "false" ]; then exit 1; fi'`

Comment: @phd How do you use that? As the first line of the Travis file? Or for a specific task?

Comment: Well, **I** don't. Exactly opposite — I test PRs before merging them into master. Not so long ago [I removed all limitations](https://github.com/sqlobject/sqlobject/commit/8fd31c32bd420f19cf02e64088436d82e936aaab). But if I would to prevent PRs I'd use the code above as the first command of test task. In `script:` section like in the linked docs.

Comment: Ah oké. Got that working. However was wondering if there was a setting that would mean the entire file would be skipped for the master branch though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to your `branches only master` setting, I believe you should disable the "Build pushed pull requests" switch in the Build Settings menu.

[image]